# Offensive comment as Post edit: A way to escape with Untracked crime

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

This is first time to see such case on the edits review queue. A 1'rep user wrote an offensive comment as an edit of a different user answer (as it could be a question).

Well, I could reject it for different reasons: Invalid edit (Attend to be a comment), Vandalism (Spam) or Custom. I preferred to write a custom message: *personal & offensive comment made as an edit*.

What should I choose in such case?

Because I thought that was a wrong choice, may be better if I choose Spam. Ideally, If there some options like comment flags. The user could get a warning (or his account will be suspended) for that, similar to writing comments.

As I did, The user will go with an untracked crime/offense and he can do that again and again.

Note: May be I'm not aware if there are some mod tools that catch such case.

- Suggested edit: https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/289624
- Related post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/493748/unable-to-make-backup-link-of-usr-share-tomcat7-bin-daemon-sh-before-instal/493750#493750

[image: offensive comment as a post edit]

Comment: also note that the gravatar is the same, so it is the same person as the answerer...

Comment: @Mateo, I agree, I thought of same person too but nothing in the hand to prove it. admins may do, they have access to adv profiles :)

Comment: The gravatar's are the same so it is the same ip address since gravatar is either based in e-mail or ip address

Comment: That edit and the answer is of mine. I got angry over that persons mal behaviour. He thinks he is the master of Ubuntu and do downvote and add his comments. I apologize for my mal behaviour. I warned him that we can also downvote all his answers too.

Comment: @BillGates, you can add a comment under your answer, asking why down vote. If you think that was wrong and needs to be reported, you can back to a mod/admin (through flag/chat/meta).

Comment: Were there any comments on the downvoted answer? If not, that would have been nice, because the user seems to have done an effort.

Comment: Oh and Sneetsher, though I understand why you ask the question here, but I am afraid it is only fuel on the fire.

Comment: @don.joey, nop, no comment was there at that time with 1 vote down. There was only 2 comments under question one by TimRiker and another by Braiam, they are still there. :D oh no... I did mean to be part of that, I hope my title was clear and very precise.

Comment: Honestly, though I do not approve @BillGates behavior (at least this BillGates'), I do think that a downvote in this case should have been followed with a comment. BG's anger is understandable.

Comment: @BillGates Take a deep breath and relax. A downvote from one member of the site (regardless of that persons opinion of themselves) is **not** a good reason to deface posts or go on a mass downvoting campaign. We are here to improve the site. Expecting that we will all agree on the best ways to do so isn't logical. Don't be upset, just move on and work harder. Eventually your detractors whomever they may be will find someone else to pick on as your work begins to speak for itself.

Comment: I accept my huge fault. I had done something nasty. I do apologize from all of you. Same time the sites answering rate is so poor relative to other stackexchange sites. When a user become afraid to reveal his knowledge(even though if it is less), that situation can increase. It is better if pointout the fault in the answer before or after downvote.

Comment: Also i have to say something. Now i am in a temporary profile. I didnt sign in. I previously had a account with more than 3000 reputation. One of my answer which had a bounty of 500 marks was hugely downvoted and remained downvoted (even the user who had problem given the bounty. So I decided to leave the Askubuntu and remain unregistered. I hate this anonymous downvoting. I posted a question about this earlier in meta but the that question was also massively downvoted.

Comment: @user296776 I realize you have apologized and all that already, but I must point several things out. a) you have no idea who downvoted you, so calling out someone just because they happen to leave a comment on the question is unproductive and silly. They may have downvoted you, they may have not. You don't know. b) threatening users, whatever the reason, is a very serious offence, even vaguely. Don't let it happen again. If you feel someone is targeting you or being rude/mean to you take it to the moderators. Thanks.

Comment: @jco Actually, it doesn't matter what meta site you post on. Posting here is perfectly OK.

Comment: @Sneetsher No, there is no real "rule" about this. It is however, important to remember that (almost) everything you do on Ask Ubuntu is public, there is no hiding it. I myself wouldn't call it a big deal, but if you like pop into [chat] and we can discuss it.

Comment: Hey, cool I'm getting propaganda :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As to what you should choose. *Vandalism* would be the correct choice here, per it's description:

> This edit introduces spam, **defaces the post** in some way, or is **otherwise inappropriate.**

You can use a custom if you would prefer, but it is best to avoid confrontation with trolls/etc. I would just use vandalism.

As to what you should do. If you see this happen please do flag the post and include a link to the suggested edit. Even if we decide to not take any action, it is much better we know then not. It is also worth noting that if the user tries to keep this up, and the edits are rejected, the system will automatically (temporarily) ban them from suggesting edits. You should *definitely* flag if you see this happen more than once.

Comment: I always choose vandalism in a case such as this. I think I've run across 3 similar examples in about the last 6 months. This clearly defaces the post and is completely inappropriate.