# Offensive comment in review queue

Tags: discussion

I've seen [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/10494/offensive-comment-as-post-edit-a-way-to-escape-with-untracked-crime) but this situation is a bit different. While going through the re-open review queue I came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/review/reopen/677942) in which the OP added a likely offensive remark into the edit comment. Although I understand their frustration I don't think it's helpful and see no need to drop an F bomb into a comment requesting re-opening of a question. What should be done in a situation such as this?

Comment: I've commented, I wouldn't do anything else.

Comment: @Tim your comment stated children might come here which is true but there is more that can be commented. ie f-bombs are more appropriate for mixed martial arts websites where children (from dubious parents) also go to. Here we try to be professional and well versed with good grammar. In essence what you would expect from a media organization as far as politeness, fairness, balance, credibility, consideration, factual and of course vulgarity free.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Sure, but that isn't clearly expressed in the rules of the website - there's be nice, but because this is in a hidden edit commit, it doesn't apply so much.

Comment: No it's not explicitly stated. I've implicitly "felt" those are the unwritten rules. After awhile the way you, I and everyone else conducts ourselves sort of makes the unwritten rules I guess :)... Oh BTW I have no idea what a "hidden edit comment" is. I looked at the link, posted a commented, posted an answer but didn't see any profanity.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix see the revision history of the post

Comment: @muru I don't know how to do that *blush*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a note, and so we can consider this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) without marking it as such (since this wasn't a request for assistance):

The specified offensive edit comment has been revised to remove the profanity.  You're right that profanity shouldn't be anywhere, even in edit messages, heh.

Answer (score 4):

Only a moderator can edit another user's edit summary. So, flag for moderator attention and have one of our nice moderators edit out the offending part.

---

In the meantime, I downvoted it because [the edit is drivel](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16665/best-way-to-end-a-question-post/16667#16667).

Comment: I couldn't agree more. It seems it got reopened anyway.

Comment: Not sure that is the right reason for downvotes...?

Comment: @Tim the edit is neither useful nor clear, which is a good enough reason for downvoting the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit I don't recall the exact order in which I performed these actions but as they were effective I will share them here.

I posted a comment on the post encouraging further editing to add detail that would help us determine why "all the answers" that were tried failed. I did not vote to re-open as I didn't feel that rewarding profanity was appropriate.

I attempted to draw attention to the problem by:

A) Opening this question (In retrospect perhaps I should have tagged it differently I'd like to here opinions on that).

B) Dropping a comment in the [Ubuntu Regulators Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/206/ubuntu-regulators) and when it appeared that room was virtually vacant also dropping a comment in the [Ask Ubuntu General Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)

C) I visited [the question called as duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58584/can-i-automatically-deactivate-my-touchpad-when-a-usb-mouse-is-connected) and edited [one of the answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/58586/225694) that I was quickly able to determine was out of date. More work is clearly required to bring this one up to current day. I'm afraid I have nothing more to offer in that regard and trust that those of us inthe community that have the necessary skills will step up further address the issue.

Clearly this approach was effective as the [Revision History](https://askubuntu.com/posts/882571/revisions) no longer contains the profanity I was concerned about.